# Request Not Authorized or Over QueryLimit' - GoogleLocationService

Tags: c#

Segue código:

```
var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress("Rua Osasco - Amador Bueno, Itapevi - SP, Brasil");
```

Erro:

> System.Net.WebException: 'Request Not Authorized or Over QueryLimit'

Esse erro acima, ocorre na segunda linha, se eu voltar o breakpoint na linha : `var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();` e depois avançar tudo, vai tudo ok. Não sei porque está gerando esse problema. Alguma solução ?

Comment: Segundo esse post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14014513/4312593, há uma limitação de requisições

Comment: Alguém sabe me dizer qual é o limite ?

Comment: 1000 solicitações por dia caso você não seja registrado, 150 mil por dia caso você seja registrado. Fonte: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage?hl=pt-br

Comment: Essa informação consome de um webservice. Se você faz a requisição anonimamente, você tem direito a poucos milhares de consultas por dia. Se você fornecer credenciais, mesmo as credenciais livres te dão acho que dezenas de milhares de requisições.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, ajudou muito.